# Additional information: Syntax error. in query expression Select Sum(column) from table

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax, expression

I want to get sum price of same FID from Faktor and insert into FinalFaktor but i see this error

> Additional information: Syntax error. in query expression 'select Sum(KPrice) From Faktor where FID like 2' when run the below code.

```
str = "insert into FinalFaktor (FID,Fdate,FTotal) Values (" & faktornumberlbl.Text & ",'" & fdate & "', 
       select Sum(KPrice) From Faktor where FID like " & faktornumberlbl.Text & ")"
        FinalFaktorTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = str
        FinalFaktorTableAdapter.Connection.Open()
        FinalFaktorTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Clear()
        FinalFaktorTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteReader()
        FinalFaktorTableAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet.FinalFaktor)
        FinalFaktorTableAdapter.Connection.Close()
```

I think problem `Select Sum("KPrice) From Faktor where FID like " & faktornumberlbl.Text`

my programming language is VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a valid `insert` from `select` syntax try this one

```
INSERT INTO FinalFaktor (FID,Fdate,FTotal) 
SELECT " & faktornumberlbl.Text & ",
       '" & fdate & "',
       Sum(KPrice)
FROM   Faktor
WHERE  FID LIKE " & faktornumberlbl.Text & "
```

Comment: Get rid of the word `VALUES` and the ending `& "`.  Also, where applicable, I'd recommend using a parameterized query instead.

Comment: @sgeddes - yeah its a typo!!